# How can I make ALB forward traffic to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm struggling to find a solution that make ALB forward traffic to API Gateway (Ideally private). Below is the flow:

Domain => ALB => API Gateway.

How can we make ALB forward traffic to private API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do this reliably. The only way I can think of is to use [IP address type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type) in your ALB's target group. This would have to be **private IP address** of your private API gateway interface endpoint in the VPC.

The problem is that private IP is probably not guaranteed to be static. Thus you should always use DNS name of the gateway, but ALB will not accept the DNS name. It can only take IP address.

So you can try and use the private IP address as target, and if IP changes too much you have to develop custom solution to monitor the IPs and update your ALB target groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcin. That is what I doing now, using the private IP from Network Interfaces attached to the API Gateway. But I faced some IP changes so that why I asked to get a better and more stable solution

Comment: @AshBlake You could have lambda on schedule monitoring those IPs and doing the updates when needed. Not sure if there is any automated notification mechanism when those IP changes.

Comment: I think I can do scripting to automatically get the right IP, but it will be very painful

Comment: @AshBlake But if the API should be accessible from the internet, why not make it actually public?

Comment: Because it should not be publicly accessible. If it can, I can use the redirect rule, am I right?

Comment: @AshBlake Yes, if it was public, you could use redirect rule.